# Extensions of oligomorphic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

Recall that a permutation group $G\le\mathfrak{S}(\mathbb N)$ is *oligomorphic* if, for any positive integer $k$, the induced $G$-action on $k$-tuples of distinct elements of $\mathbb N$ has only finitely many orbits.
Let's say that a countable group is *oligomorphic* if it is isomorphic (as an abstract group) to some oligomorphic permutation group.

Given a short exact sequence of (abstract) countable groups $1\to K \to G \to Q \to 1$, with $Q$ oligomorphic (or even $K$ and $Q$ oligomorphic), are there conditions on the sequence which guarantee that $G$ is oligomorphic?

**EDIT:** I would even be interested by the case where $K$ is finite. One motivation for me is the following. If $G$ is oligomorphic whenever there is a short exact sequence of (abstract) groups $1\to K \to G \to Q \to 1$, with $K$ finite and $Q$ countable oligomorphic, then every acylindrically hyperbolic group is oligomorphic. Indeed Hull and Osin proved in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-016-1411-9) ([ArXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04182)) that every acylindrically hyperbolic group admits a highly transitive action with finite kernel.